# What's the proper way to convert a Vector3DF into byte array?

Tags: c#, wpf, foreach, arrays

I am implementing Kinect's FaceTrackingBasics-WPF C# code to track the position of some object.
Tried to collect a Vector3DF type variable into some byte array using Buffer.BlockCopy as follows:

```
                    this.facePoints3D = frame.Get3DShape();
                    foreach (Vector3DF[] vector in facePoints3D.GetSlices(n))
                    {                     
                         byte[] bytearray = new byte[vector.Length * this.facePoints3D.Count];
                         Buffer.BlockCopy(vector, 0, bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
                    }
```

but I am having a Buffer.BlockCopy ArgumentException of "src or dst is not an array of primitives." each time I run the execution file. I know this is 'cause Vector3DF is not a primitive.

Now for reference, the vector3DF is defined as:

```
    public struct Vector3DF
     {
       public Vector3DF(float x, float y, float z)
        : this()
       {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
        }
       // ...       
        //some more code
       //...
     }
```

Is there a good way to convert this so-called Vector3DF to bytearray so I can pass it onto memory?
Thanks!

Comment: data is already in memory, what you actually want to do? pass to pointer?

Comment: Well, not exactly @pushpraj, because the conversion from Vector3DF vector to byte is not of primitive. I am asking how to properly convert from float(in this case Vector3DF) to bytearray. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a way using interop techniques

```
    //sample data
    Vector3DF v3df = new Vector3DF(10, 20, 30);

    //get data size
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(v3df);

    //allocate memory
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

    //copy data to memory
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(v3df, ptr, false);

    //copy data from memory to byte array
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    //release memory
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

see if this helps you achieve what you want

Comment: Thanks, But why do I have to send the data to memory before converting to bytearray?

Comment: {"Type 'Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.FaceTracking.Vector3DF[]' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed."}

Comment: @Calorified, this approach works with structures of definite size as the example struct defined in the question. could you post full code of the structure `Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.FaceTracking.Vector3DF[]`? may we try to find a workaround for the same.

Comment: Lines 354 to 422 of the link: https://github.com/rayliaw/SFMFaceTracker/blob/master/Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.FaceTracking/Utils.cs

Comment: @Calorified, the struct looks completely ok. It seems like you are trying to do the whole array at once, try one by one item. perhaps you may combine them all at the end.